# JQuery add/remove class Not Working properly on Chrome Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
$('.notice-label').addClass('hide')
$('#loc-create-boolean').on('click', (e) => {
  let locBoolean = $('#loc-create-boolean').find(':selected').text();
  if (locBoolean === 'Yes') {
    $('.notice-label').removeClass('hide')
  } else {
    $('.notice-label').addClass('hide')
  }
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="violation-dropdown-cont">
  <p id="loc-create">Was a notice created for this location?<span class="required">
                            *</span></p>
  <select name="loc-create" id="loc-create-boolean">
    <option value="" disabled selected class="loc-boolean-dropdown">Select One</option>
    <option value="Yes" class="loc-boolean-dropdown">Yes</option>
    <option value="no" class="loc-boolean-dropdown">No</option>
  </select>
</div>
<span class="notice-label">Message</span>
```

I've built a mobile application and the functionality was testing fine on Chrome dev tools (desktop) but when I published the site and visited it on my phone the `.removeClass` and `.addClass` were not working with the click events. It works, but only when it's clicked a second time.

Any clues why the click event would work as expected on the desktop dev environment, but not on the actual Android device?

Answer (score 0):

The click event may not always be utilized to represent a click on Android. To solve your issue, listen to the touchend event.

Example:

```js
$('.notice-label').addClass('hide')
$('#loc-create-boolean').on('click', (e) => {
  let locBoolean = $('#loc-create-boolean').find(':selected').text();
  if (locBoolean === 'Yes') {
    $('.notice-label').removeClass('hide');
  } else {
    $('.notice-label').addClass('hide')
  }
});
// Somee thing like this, also check othe touch option as per your requirement.
$(document).on("touchend", function(e) {
  var target = $(event.target).attr('id');
  if (target === "loc-create-boolean")
    $('#loc-create-boolean').trigger('click');
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="violation-dropdown-cont">
  <p id="loc-create">Was a notice created for this location?<span class="required">
                        *</span></p>
  <select name="loc-create" id="loc-create-boolean">
    <option value="" disabled selected class="loc-boolean-dropdown">Select One</option>
    <option value="Yes" class="loc-boolean-dropdown">Yes</option>
    <option value="no" class="loc-boolean-dropdown">No</option>
  </select>
  <span class="notice-label">Message</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This unfortunately does not solve the issue.